# Consistently getting Type errors even when typecasting

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a bit of code to work out the average percentage of crRng over the past 5 (of fewer) years.

Below is the snippet of my code which I'm having trouble with:

```
'get number of rows
    Range("I1").End(xlDown).Select
    numRows = Selection.Row-1
    Cells(numRows+4, 8).Value = "Last 5 years"
    Cells(numRows+4, 9).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
'sumproduct last 5 years
    If numRows >= 5 Then
        If (Cells(numRows+1, 1).Value - Cells(numRows-4, 1).Value) = 4 Then
        crRng = Range(Cells(numRows+1, 9), Cells(numRows-4, 9))
        epRng = Range(Cells(numRows+1, 3), Cells(numRows-4, 3))
        Cells(numRows+4, 9).Select
        'Selection = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(crRng, epRng)/WorksheetFunction.Sum(epRng)
        Selection.Value = "sumproduct(" & crRng & ", " & epRng & ")/sum(" & epRng & ")"
        Else
        End If
    Else
        crRng = Range(Cells(numRows+1, 9), Cells(2, 9))
        epRng = Range(Cells(numRows+1, 3), Cells(2, 3))
        Cells(numRows+4, 9).Select
        Selection.Value = "sumproduct(" & crRng & ", " & epRng & ")/sum(" & epRng & ")"
    End If
```

The code worked fine before adding this in-cell formula (a necessity unfortunately) and the second if. As far as I can see, the only problematic lines are the new lines I added (changing the `Selection.Value` formula from what is commented out to the new one, and the nested If).

Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong? I have tried typecasting all values to CInt() and that has not worked - can user-defined ranges not be used like this? I have done similar things before and have never had a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I'd start with removing all `.select` and `Selection.`. you can use statements like `Cells(numRows+4, 9).Formula = "=sumproduct(" & crRng & ", " & epRng & ")/sum(" & epRng & ")"` instead

Comment: You might also want to adjust the ranges in the formula with `& crRng.Address &`

Comment: You can't put a formula into a cell's Value. Use Formula instead. Also, you will want to add a '=' in front of the formula.

Comment: You *can* add a formula into a cell's `.Value` but you *shouldn't*. @Paul

Comment: `Cells(numRows+1, 9), Cells(numRows-4, 9))` is 6 rows - is that correct ? What is the `If (Cells(numRows+1, 1).Value - Cells(numRows-4, 1).Value) = 4 Then` for ?

Comment: @Notus_Panda You are right: you can, but it doesn't work :-)

Comment: Try it out @Paul `Range("A1").Value = "=SUM(" & Range("B1:B2").Address & "," & Range("C1:C2").Address & ")"` and check A1 then. It works but you shouldn't let VBA guess what you mean hence why we use `.Formula/.Formula1/.FormulaLocal` depending on the situation.

Comment: @Notus_Panda you are right, must have made a typo when I tried it earlier

Comment: @CDP1802 it's a fair question - it's to make sure those values are 4 years apart - the data I'm extracting should pass the check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"sumproduct(" & crRng & " etc` requires `crRng` to be a string like `$I$2:$I$6` i.e. a `Range().Address` rather than an array of values which `Range()` returns. Also `Range().Resize(r,c)` is a useful way of expanding a range to a number or rows (or columns).

```vb
Sub example()

    Const NUM = 5 ' years to calc
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, startrow As Long, n As Long
    Dim epAddr As String, crAddr As String, f As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        ' check xlDown will be valid
        If IsEmpty(.Range("I2")) Then
            MsgBox "I2 empty", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
        End If
        
         ' determine startrow and lastrow
        lastrow = .Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row
        startrow = IIf(lastrow <= NUM, 2, lastrow + 1 - NUM)
        n = lastrow - startrow + 1

        ' check year difference
        If .Range("A" & lastrow) - .Range("A" & startrow) + 1 <> n Then
            MsgBox "Years in Rows " & startrow & " and " & lastrow & _
                   " do not span " & n & " years", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' range addresses
        epAddr = .Range("C" & startrow).Resize(n).Address
        crAddr = .Range("I" & startrow).Resize(n).Address
        
        ' formula
        f = "=SUMPRODUCT(" & crAddr & ", " & epAddr & ")/SUM(" & epAddr & ")"
        
        With .Range("I" & lastrow).Offset(3)
            .Offset(, -1) = "Last 5 years"
            .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            .Formula = f
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Completely forgot about .Address - thank you! I know my use of .Select and .Selection is a bit much so this is helping me cut down from that addiction...